# Finding the max and min values and printing the line from a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a file which has numbers at the first column.

```
100,red
101,blue
102,black
```

I should write a shell script that it will print the line with the maximum and minimum numbers.

```
max=0
cat file.txt|while read LINE
do
    fir=`echo $LINE|awk '{print $2}'`
    sec=`echo $LINE|awk '{print $3}'`
    if [ $fir -gt $max ]; then
       max=$fir
    fi
    if [ $sec -gt $max ];then
        max=$sec
    fi
done

grep $max file.txt
```

This is what I tried so far for finding the maximum.

Comment: a very "expensive" way to parse your lines AND why are you looking at `...awk '{print $3}'` ... you only have 2 elements? @sudo_O is right, awk is best here, but if you're just trying to learn shell coding, then reduce it to `while read fir sec ; do if [ $fir .... done < file.txt` . Good luck.

Comment: `max` is being set in a subshell induced by the pipeline. Simply change to `while read LINE; do ...; done < file.txt`. But as others have pointed out, this is very expensive.

Comment: You should write a shell script? Is this kind of homework?

Answer (score 38):

For min value:

```
[bash]$ cut -f1 -d"," file_name | sort -n | head -1
```

For max value:

```
[bash]$ cut -f1 -d"," file_name | sort -n | tail -1
```

Comment: This solution works, but isn't sorting much more expensive ( O(n log n) ) than just finding the minimum ( O (log n) )? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Hi,you may try this: awk -v max=0 '{if($1>max){want=$2; max=$1}}END{print want} ' file_name

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively using sort and sed

```
$ sort -n id | sed -n '1p;$p'
100 red
102 black
```

`-n` flag - sort as numbers.

How to use it:

```
$ a=($(sort -n id | sed -n '1s/^\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/p;$s/^\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/p'))
$ echo "min=${a[0]}, max=${a[1]}"
min=100, max=102
```

Comment: This is a simple and elegant solution!

Answer (score 6):

You should just do the whole thing in `awk` if you have `GNU awk`:

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$1]=$0}END{asorti(a,b);print a[b[1]]"\n"a[b[NR]]}' file
100,red
102,black
```

If you don't:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1{s=m=$1}{a[$1]=$0;m=($1>m)?$1:m;s=($1<s)?$1:s}END{print a[s]"\n"a[m]}' file
100,red
102,black
```

---

Alternatively presort and print the first and last line:

```
$ sort -t',' -nk1 file | awk 'NR==1;END{print}'
100,red
102,black
```

Comment: thank you, but i get a 'function asorti never defined' error, also i want to print the whole line, not only the number.

Comment: What system are you on? You don't have `GNU awk` it seems.

Comment: second one works great, but sorry for forgetting something that i have a comma between the numbers and colors

Comment: I like the solutions. Scripting languages are really handy for common day tasks. I enjoy their availability with the minimal (code) overhead to test things out / prototyping.

Answer (score 3):

```
[bash]$ cat log
100,red
101,blue
102,black
[bash]$ all=( $(sort log | cut -f1 -d',') )
[bash]$ echo "MIN: ${all[0]} and MAX: ${all[${#all[@]}-1]}"
MIN: 100 and MAX: 102
```

Create an array using the sorted elements. First and last elements are containing the min and max values

Comment: You want to be sorting numerical on the first field `sort -t',' -nk1 file`.

Answer (score 1):

In zip CSV file

## For the Min value

`bzcat file.csv.bz2 | cut -f2 -d";" | sort -n | head -2`

## For the max value

`bzcat file.csv.bz2 | cut -f2 -d";" | sort -n | tail -1`

Regadrs,

Ali

Comment: How is this relevant? OP stated (implicitly) that he is given a plain text file.

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is also very beautiful, and I hope it will be useful for someone in the future, suppose you have this data:

```
$ cat file.txt
red,100
blue,101
black,90
```

now with **[GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)**

```
$ <file.txt datamash -t, -sg1 min 2
```

result

```
black,90
blue,101
red,100
```

`-t,` specifies that the columns in the input data are separated by commas

`-s`: ensures that the input data is sorted based on the grouping column(s) before performing any calculations

`-g1`: groups the data based on the values in the first column

`min 2`: it calculates the minimum value in the second column for each unique value in the first column