# Get smallest line in a file (smallest based on string lexicographic order)

Tags: linux, shell, min, lexicographic-ordering

Given a file that contains:

```
2011-03-01
2011-04-01
2011-01-01
2011-05-01
2011-02-01
```

I would like to get:

```
2011-01-01
```

which is the smallest line in the file if we compare the lines based on their lexicographic order.

One way of achieving this is to sort the lines first then return the first line:

```
sort file | head -n 1
```

However this is has a complexity of O(*n* log*n*) due to `sort` while min operation should be doable in a mere O(*n*) where *n* is the number of lines.

Anyone knows of a smarter and/or more efficient way of performing this?

Comment: It's 2018, I'm surprised this question was not previously asked. maybe I didn't use the right keywords to look it up?

Comment: [Finding the max and min values and printing the line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16212410/608639), [find the max value of column 1 and print respective record from column 2 from file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170205/56041), etc.

Comment: solutions using `sort` involve a whole lot of unnecessary operations and therefore do not scale well. like I've mentioned above, I'm interested in an O(n) solution.

Comment: You should visit all the answers and not just the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `awk 'NR==1 || $0 < min {min=$0} END {print min}' file`, time it and see if it's any faster than `sort|head`

Comment: noticeably faster. In my dataset of 38M records `awk` sol'n runs ~6x faster than `sort` when finding `min` while finding `max` is ~10x faster with `awk` compared to `sort|tail`